# Action Script 3: substr output

Tags: string, actionscript-3

What would actionscript output in the following examples?

```
var str  = "Hello from Paris, Texas!!!"; 

str.substring(11,15)) 
str.substring(15,11)) 
str.substring(15,2)) 
str.substring(15,2)) 
str.substring(0,15)) 
str.substring(15,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

The function behaves the same as it does in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

> If indexA is larger than indexB, then the effect of substring() is as
>   if the two arguments were swapped; for example, str.substring(1, 0) ==
>   str.substring(0, 1).

So the results would be:

```
1. "Pari"
2. "Pari"
3. "llo from Pari"
4. "llo from Pari"
5. "Hello from Pari"
6. "Hello from Pari"
```

I don't have any Flash authoring tools installed (I presume you don't either or you wouldn't be asking the question), so I used this [online ActionScript 3.0 compiler](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/#) to test the behaviour. However, since ActionScript 3.0 is based on an earlier ECMAScript standard, you can usually rely on the results of tests conducted in the browser console to understand how a built in function will behave in the Flash Player.