# Actionscript - substring

Tags: actionscript-3

How does Actionscript handle the following substrings? 
For the substrings below, what are the correct outputs?

```
var main = "1234567890"
var output = substring(main, 5,1) // output = 
var output = substring(main, 1,5) // output = 
var output = substring(main, 0,5) // output = 
var output = substring(main, 5,0) // output =
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action Script 3: substr output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124844/action-script-3-substr-output)

Comment: Not a duplicate, substr and substring are different functions.

Comment: Both your questions ask about substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`String.substring`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substring%28%29) function gives :

```
var main:String = "1234567890";

trace(main.substring(5, 1));    // gives : 2345
trace(main.substring(1, 5));    // gives : 2345
trace(main.substring(0, 5));    // gives : 12345
trace(main.substring(5, 0));    // gives : 12345
```

For this function, if the first param (startIndex) is greater than the second one (endIndex) the parameters are automatically swapped before the function executes.
So :

```
string.substring(5, 1) == string.substring(1, 5)
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

The proper code will be using [`String.subString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substring%28%29) method, and look like this:

```
var main:String="1234567890";
var output:String=main.subString(5,1); // output = "2345"
var output:String=main.subString(1,5); // output = "2345"
var output:String=main.subString(0,5); // output = "12345"
var output:String=main.subString(5,0); // output = "12345"
```

The parameters are `startIndex` and `endIndex`, they are 0-based, and the character at `endIndex` is not included in the returned substring.

EDIT: Indeed the manual states that the parameters are swapped if `endIndex` is smaller than `startIndex`. Weird, I must say. But if they are equal, the result is an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify, why is the second exampls output empty? (ie. substring(5,1))?

Comment: endIndex < startIndex, empty string. The second parameter is not length!

Comment: So subString(1,1) would also be empty?

Comment: @Vesper I don't agree with your answer, and if the value of startIndex is greater than the value of endIndex, the parameters are automatically swapped before the function executes, as Adobe said.

Comment: Fixed the post, see reviewed answer. Sorry, but @akmozo noticed that I'm wrong partly.